# How to convert string like [{'id':1'}] to list [{'id':1'}] Data Type in Python?

Tags: python

Actually i have the output like

```
[{'images': 'static/files/7_8731.jpg', 'p_weight': '4kg', 'p_id': '8731', 'p_name': 'Chicken', 'c_name': 'Eggs, Meat & Fish', 'p_cost': '1000', 'c_id': '7'}, {'images': 'static/files/6_3124.jpg', 'p_weight': '3pcs', 'p_id': '3124', 'p_name': 'Mobs', 'c_name': 'Cleaning & Houshold', 'p_cost': '1500', 'c_id': '6'}, {'images': 'static/files/1_8460.jpg', 'p_weight': '4kg', 'p_id': '8460', 'p_name': 'Healthy Fruit Mixer', 'c_name': 'Fruits & Vegetables', 'p_cost': '1000', 'c_id': '1'}, {'images': 'static/files/5_7110.jpg', 'p_weight': '1kg', 'p_id': '7110', 'p_name': 'French fries', 'c_name': 'Snacks', 'p_cost': '500', 'c_id': '5'}]
```

The type of this data is string and i want to change this data into list with same structure in python..please can anyone help me..

Comment: Can you provide the input params?

Comment: use json library in python

Comment: i cant get you @mohammad this input is from html to python   EX:val = request.form['vals']    herein vals in passed the values from html to python but html values is list.

Comment: Try: `import ast; python_object = ast.literal_eval(your_string)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json package accepts only double quotes so we should first convert the string to have `"` instead of `'` and then `load` data

```
import json

list_str = "[{'images': 'static/files/7_8731.jpg', 'p_weight': '4kg', 'p_id': '8731', 'p_name': 'Chicken', 'c_name': 'Eggs, Meat & Fish', 'p_cost': '1000', 'c_id': '7'}, {'images': 'static/files/6_3124.jpg', 'p_weight': '3pcs', 'p_id': '3124', 'p_name': 'Mobs', 'c_name': 'Cleaning & Houshold', 'p_cost': '1500', 'c_id': '6'}, {'images': 'static/files/1_8460.jpg', 'p_weight': '4kg', 'p_id': '8460', 'p_name': 'Healthy Fruit Mixer', 'c_name': 'Fruits & Vegetables', 'p_cost': '1000', 'c_id': '1'}, {'images': 'static/files/5_7110.jpg', 'p_weight': '1kg', 'p_id': '7110', 'p_name': 'French fries', 'c_name': 'Snacks', 'p_cost': '500', 'c_id': '5'}]"
list_python = json.loads(list_str.replace('\'', '"'))
```